# "not authorized" on this computer when syncing iphone to mac even though authorization already performed

Tags: iphone, itunes

Even though this computer is already authorized for iTunes:

[image]

Following the directions on the warning message as seen in the screenshot:

I did authenticate this computer

```
    Store | Authorize this computer
```

(which btw had already been authenticated in the past - so I don't know why it lost the auth..).  But the error message continues to happen.

[image]

So then we are in a catch22. iTunes say I am already authorized but then turns around and says I am not. I have repeated this process to ensure it were not just temporary.  Why the discrepancy here - and what to do to resolve?

Comment: sometimes it's just best to clear all authorisations & start over - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204385

Comment: @Tetsujin I did reauthorize (i.e. re-enter the iTunes Store password) but behavior persists.

Comment: did you clear all authorisations first?