# iPhone 5 syncing

Tags: iphone, itunes

when syncing, the error message reads "The iPhone "David's iPhone" could not be synced because this computer is no longer authorized for purchased items that are on this iPhone." [click OK]
then, 
"To authorize this computer for items purchased from the iTunes store, choose Account>Authorizations>Authorize this computer."

When I do this, the message reads "This computer is already authorized."

So then, why won't it sync?

Comment: I voted this question down because I believe [it is a duplicate](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223528/not-authorized-on-this-computer-when-syncing-iphone-to-mac-even-though-authori). Please use the search bar in the upper right corner and research your issue before posting. If you believe your situation differs from those posts before you, please edit your question and include facts indicating your circumstance. You may want to consider adding links to those relevant questions and be specific on how they do not solve your issue.

Comment: @Frysk I don't believe it's fair to vote down this question because your linked question **has no answers**. So I've upvoted it.

Comment: @JohnRamos In the comments it suggests clearing all authorizations and then re-authorizing. I did some research on the topic and found this to be a possible answer. The OP did not say whether or not they tried this and if it helped, or what they found in their own research. I'm still *really* new at this and learning the culture. I won't vote down for such a thing in the future.

Comment: @Frysk No worries, and welcome to Ask Different. It's fine to flag it as a duplicate (you can hit `flag` and then `duplicate`), just maybe post that one as an answer first.

Comment: Though it's fine to flag a post as a duplicate, you can't if the original has no accepted or upvoted answers. It would be well worth checking if a full de-authorise/re-authorise will work in this case, then we can work towards a canonical question/answer.

Comment: Just because the OP successfully authorized with their Apple ID doesn't mean there isn't content on the device originally purchased with a different Apple ID, which isn't authorized on that Mac.